# Bootstrap button group not same size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im currently working on bootstrap web framework and i'm encountering some issue on how to align all the button groups to fit to whatever text size inside of the button?

html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1">
<title>Button Groups</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{ url_for('static',filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>


<style>
.flash-button{  
    animation-name: flash;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    //Firefox 1+
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    //Safari 3-4
    -moz-animation-name: flash;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes flash {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

//Firefox 1+
@-webkit-keyframes flash {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

//Safari 3-4
@-moz-keyframes flash {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

.btn-space {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.responsive-width {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
.btn{
    white-space:normal !important;
    word-wrap:break-word; 
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<h2>Button Groups</h2>

 <div class = "row btn-space">
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button1')">User</button>
        <button type="button" id="button2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button2')">Status 2</button> 
        <button type="button" id="button3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button3')">Status 3</button>
        <button type="button" id="button4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button4')">Status 4</button>
 </div></br></br>
 </div>

<div class = "row btn-space">
     <div class="btn-group col-xs-12">
         <button type="button" id="button5" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button5')">Status 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="button6" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button6')">Status 2</button> 
        <button type="button" id="button7" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button7')">Status 3</button>
        <button type="button" id="button8" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button8')">Status 4</button>
</div></br></br>
</div>

<div class = "row btn-space">
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-12">
 <button type="button" id="button9" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button9')">Status 1</button>
 <button type="button" id="button10" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button10')">Status 2</button> 
 <button type="button" id="button11" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button11')">Status 3</button>
 <button type="button" id="button12" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button12')">Status 4</button></div></br></br>
</div>
</div>


<script>
    var button1 = 1;
    var button2 = 1;
    var button3 = 1;
    var button4 = 1;
    function changeClass(btn) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        switch(btn){
            case 'button1':
                if (button1 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    button1 = 1;       
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button3').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button4').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-success btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button1 = 0;
                    button2 = 1;
                    button3 = 1;
                    button4 = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'button2':
                if (button2 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg  col-xs-3';
                    button2 = 1;     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button3').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button4').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-warning btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button2 = 0;
                    button1 = 1;
                    button3 = 1;
                    button4 = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'button3':
                if (button3 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    button3 = 1;     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button4').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-danger btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button3 = 0;
                    button1 = 1;
                    button2 = 1;
                    button4 = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'button4':
                if (button4 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    button4 = 1;     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button3').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-danger btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button4 = 0;
                    button1 = 1;
                    button2 = 1;
                    button3 = 1;
                }
                break;
        } 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the 1st button is not aligned to its incorporated group.

[image]

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You had some problem in your markup. It should be `<br> not </br>`.
Also the content is different for user button and state buttons. so same padding won't work. Providing an example snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var button1 = 1;
    var button2 = 1;
    var button3 = 1;
    var button4 = 1;
    function changeClass(btn) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        switch(btn){
            case 'button1':
                if (button1 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    button1 = 1;       
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button3').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button4').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-success btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button1 = 0;
                    button2 = 1;
                    button3 = 1;
                    button4 = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'button2':
                if (button2 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg  col-xs-3';
                    button2 = 1;     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button3').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button4').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-warning btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button2 = 0;
                    button1 = 1;
                    button3 = 1;
                    button4 = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'button3':
                if (button3 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    button3 = 1;     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button4').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-danger btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button3 = 0;
                    button1 = 1;
                    button2 = 1;
                    button4 = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'button4':
                if (button4 == 0) {
                    property.className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    button4 = 1;     
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    document.getElementById('button3').className = 'btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3';
                    property.className += 'btn btn-danger btn-lg flash-button col-xs-3';
                    button4 = 0;
                    button1 = 1;
                    button2 = 1;
                    button3 = 1;
                }
                break;
        } 
    }
```

```css
.flash-button{  
    animation-name: flash;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    //Firefox 1+
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    //Safari 3-4
    -moz-animation-name: flash;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes flash {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

//Firefox 1+
@-webkit-keyframes flash {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

//Safari 3-4
@-moz-keyframes flash {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.5; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

.btn-space {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
     
}

.responsive-width {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
.btn{
    white-space:normal !important;
    word-wrap:break-word; 
    padding: 25px !important;
}
#button1 {
line-height: 1.35;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial-scale=1">
<title>Button Groups</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<h2>Button Groups</h2>

 <div class = "row btn-space">
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button1')">User</button>
        <button type="button" id="button2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button2')">Status 2</button> 
        <button type="button" id="button3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button3')">Status 3</button>
        <button type="button" id="button4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button4')">Status 4</button>
 </div><br><br>
 </div>

<div class = "row btn-space">
     <div class="btn-group col-xs-12">
         <button type="button" id="button5" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button5')">Status 1</button>
        <button type="button" id="button6" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button6')">Status 2</button> 
        <button type="button" id="button7" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button7')">Status 3</button>
        <button type="button" id="button8" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button8')">Status 4</button>
</div><br><br>
</div>

<div class = "row btn-space">
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-12">
 <button type="button" id="button9" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button9')">Status 1</button>
 <button type="button" id="button10" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button10')">Status 2</button> 
 <button type="button" id="button11" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button11')">Status 3</button>
 <button type="button" id="button12" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-3" onclick="changeClass('button12')">Status 4</button></div><br><br>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi sir thank you for your positive response, but when im trying to run code snippet compare to copy and paste it to create an html, it has a different out come, the runcode snippet are much more the answer compare to the snippet that i copy and paste to check on my localhost?

Comment: Hi Sir , i managed to work it correct some minor issues. 

How can i fixed the text inside the button sir while changing the button size?

Comment: when i run it on chrome and hit F12 and set to s5 the alignment are not aligned again as well as the text goes down ? are there a ways to fixed it? hope you can help me

Comment: @iamcoder I have added the line-height property in my snippet. can you check if this helps.

Comment: hi sir, it doesn't work either. When it reach it's small limit the text inside the button separate and create two line feed but the 1st button text still one line feed that makes the button group not properly aligned. 
May'be adding javascript will need for this task?